# AppleScript to delete iphone photos using Image Capture App

Tags: ios, macos, scripting, applescript

I need an Applescript that will launch Image Capture on my Mac, navigate to the connected iOS device, select all of the photos, and delete them. I've managed to do everything except being able to delete the photos. There is a delete button at the bottom of the screen, and you can also right-click delete but I have not found a way to be able to do this.

Has anyone done this before, or can help me finish the script? I would attach what I already have for the first steps, but I do not have access to the script at this moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Edit:
This is what I have so far:
P.s this is impossible on a cellphone...

`tell application "Image Capture" to activate`

`tell application "System Events" to tell process "Image Capture"`

`select (row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 whose value of static text 1 of UI element 1 is "my iPhone")`

```
  delay 15
```

`keystroke "a" using {command down}`

`end tell`

Comment: In reality, any method to automate deleting a large amount of photos on an iPhone is what I am after

Comment: Can you please post the script that you currently have at the moment?

Comment: Ok posted what I have.

Comment: Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: I tried to come up with a solution but my version of the application does not have a delete button https://i.imgur.com/i2MpuvK.png

Comment: Weird. I've seen this version though...not sure if it's older or newer. Can you right click to delete?

Comment: There is no delete option with right-click for me.  Latest version of Sierra